# Not able to show desktop, 18

Tags: 18.04

I'm not able to show my desktop with either <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> nor <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> in Ubuntu 18, I was able to do it in Ubuntu 16.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had a problem with my own keyboard-shortcuts, I wasn't able to find wich one it was, so I pressed "reset all" and now it works:

[image]